# Import asymmetric key in AWS KMS

Tags: rsa, amazon-kms

Is it possible to import private key used in RSA into AWS KMS?

We want to migrate locally stored RSA keys into AWS KMW, but from UI and documentation it looks like it's only possible to import symmetric keys. Am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're right. According the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html), KMS doesn't support importing asymmetric key material:

> Imported key material is supported only for symmetric KMS keys in AWS KMS key stores, including multi-Region symmetric KMS keys.